# Error Number: 1054 Unknown column in where clause

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

> Error Number: 1054
>   Unknown column 'Motherboard' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT id_categoria from categorias WHERE nombre=Motherboard
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/computhron_ci/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

I've my code here:

[image]

Comment: Please find a basic SQL tutorial, which will teach you how to properly use character strings in places like WHERE clauses. Also, images of code are totally useless here. Please see [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons not to post your code as an image.

Comment: Paste the code in the question not image of the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your where clause, you need to wrap the value you want to filter by in quotes.